SwipeLeft and SwipeRight not working together, Android
I have in my activity (PermanentSchemes) on an ImageView (scheme1) a SwipeLeft and a SwipeRight action, the first opens the activity Schemes and the other the new activity PermanentSchemes2.
scheme1.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(PermanentSchemes.this) {
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                startActivity(new Intent(PermanentSchemes.this, Schemes.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left);
                finish();
            }
        });

scheme1.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(PermanentSchemes.this) {
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                startActivity(new Intent(PermanentSchemes.this, PermanentSchemes2.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
                finish();

            }
        });

After some testing it looks like the 2 action works well when alone, but if i have both in the code, only the last one works, making the first of the two swipes do nothing. I took the Swipe code online some time ago and this is the code. What am i doing wrong?
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}


